# oracle extractvalue concatenate values for tag names in another table

Tags: oracle, concatenation, xmltype, xmltable, extract-value

i have a strange scenario where i have 2 tables with following type of data,

```
table1: 
key1, xmldata1


    1,<start><dat1>hi/dat1><dat2>hello</dat2>........</end>
    2,<start><dat1>hihi/dat1><dat2>hellohello</dat2>.......</end>

table2:
key1, fld1, name1

    1, dat1, message1
    2, dat1, message2
    2, dat2, message3
```

I need to produce an output so that both the table is joined using key1 and for column fld1 in table2, i should join the values matching to the tag name from xmldata1 in table1. for ex:- the output should be

```
1, message1=hi
2, message2=hihi
2, message3=hellohello
```

Is that even possible? dat1, dat2, dat3 tags in table1 xmldata1 is dynamic and can have 'n' dat tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible ...

```
select T2.key1, T2.name1, xmlcast(T1.xmldata1.extract('/start/'||T2.fld1) as varchar2(4000)) as message
from table2 T2
    join table1 T1
        on T1.key1 = T2.key1
;
```

or

```
select T2.key1, T2.name1, extractvalue(T1.xmldata1, '/start/'||T2.fld1) as message
from table2 T2
    join table1 T1
        on T1.key1 = T2.key1
;
```